# Run AsyncTask only once when application starts for the first time

Tags: android, android-asynctask, sharedpreferences

I want to run AsyncTask in android only once when application starts for the first time.

I tried to put Shared preference in onCreate but it didn't work. Any other ideas ?

```
SharedPreferences prefscrt = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        if(!prefscrt.getBoolean("firstTime", false)) {
        Log.d("DownloadManager", "Installing First Time");  

new Task().execute();  //THIS WON'T WORK


SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefscrt.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("firstTime", true);
        editor.commit();
        }
```

Thanks in advance
Madz

Comment: wheres the if condition checking that whether or not the shared preference contains "firstTime" = true?

Comment: Fahad - Thanks for replying. This Shared preference code is working fine. I am currently using the same thing for one method during onCreate and it is working. My only concern is why it won't consider 

new Task().execute(); line ??

Comment: Then please post your AsyncTask code

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("firstTime", MODE_PRIVATE);
registartion = prefs.getBoolean("firstTime", false);
```

and now put your if condition

Comment: Thanks for replying. This Shared preference code is working fine. I am currently using the same thing for one method during onCreate and it is working. My only concern is why it won't consider new Task().execute(); line ??

Comment: @user1223035 can u check whether onPreExecute() getting called or not??

Answer (score 0):

> 1.First check the value is null or not if null then sharedpref use and save them..
>   2.But in second time again check if they have already sharedpref run your code .

```
private Boolean firstTime = null;
  SharedPreferences mPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("first_time", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  firstTime = mPreferences.getBoolean("firstTime", true);
  private boolean isFirstTime() {
 if(firstTime == null) {
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();
      editor.putBoolean("firstTime", false);
      editor.commit();
      new Task().execute(); 
  if (firstTime!=null) {

    }
}
return firstTime;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. This Shared preference code is working fine. I am currently using the same thing for one method during onCreate and it is working. My only concern is why it won't consider new Task().execute(); line ??